# How do I fix folder references inside of Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, directory

I made a huge mistake when I tried to delete a file on my project. So, I tried to reorganize it all again, but I ended up messing up everything. When I reopened the Xcode project I got all the folders filled as blue color instead of the standard yellow. After that if I run the project I got only a black screen. How do I fix that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming you don't use version control and can't just roll the project back to a previous version?

Comment: Hello dude, I was using Git Kraken. However, it also kinda "lost the folder references", I really don't know what I should do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to fix by creating another Xcode Project, then once I already had all files containing the code and also because the project is just starting I copied the files and paste, same for the storyboard, then I just setup the outlets correctly. Everything is working perfectly!

***PS:*** Don't forget to use a version control such as: Git Kraken, Source Tree and etc. Because if you face an error like the one I did you'll waste your development time to fix an error provided by a simple lack of attention. If I had a version control, I would just rollback the project in one minute.

Comment: You could also select everything and delete it by reference (do not select move to trash). Then go to finder and drag and drop the folders containing your code and assets for your project back in to the xcodeproj. It should add all the references back in automatically. I do this sometimes simply to reorder everything alphabetically.